# Combine output from 3 queries into a single query

Tags: mysql, pivot, data

I have the following three queries:

```
SELECT NAME,
    ABS(sum(UNITS)) as WK1 
FROM products 
    inner join stockdiary on  stockdiary.PRODUCT = products.ID  
where SUB_CATEGORY='LB40' 
    and DATENEW BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 7 DAY ) AND CURDATE( ) 
    and REASON = (-1) 
group by NAME 
order by CATEGORY;
```

```
SELECT NAME,
    ABS(sum(UNITS)) as WK2 
FROM products 
    inner join stockdiary on  stockdiary.PRODUCT = products.ID  
where SUB_CATEGORY='LB40' 
    and DATENEW between  curdate() - interval 14 day and curdate() - interval 8 day 
    and REASON = (-1) 
group by NAME 
order by CATEGORY;
```

```
SELECT NAME,
    ABS(sum(UNITS)) as wk3 
FROM products 
    inner join stockdiary on  stockdiary.PRODUCT = products.ID  
where SUB_CATEGORY='LB40' 
    and DATENEW between  curdate() - interval 21 day and curdate() - interval 15 day 
    and REASON = (-1) 
group by NAME 
order by CATEGORY;
```

Sample output from one of the queries:

| NAME | WK2 |
| --- | --- |
| Longbeach 40/160 Original Ctn | 2 |
| Longbeach 40/160 Menthol Fresh Ctn | 1 |
| Longbeach 40 Fine Flavour Pkt | 9 |
| Longbeach 40 Rich Flavour Pkt | 9 |
| Longbeach 40 Menthol Fresh Pkt | 5 |
| Longbeach 40 Menthol Pkt | 6 |
| Longbeach 40 Select Pkt | 5 |

How can I join the queries to get the following results?

| NAME | WK1 | WK2 | WK3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Longbeach 40/160 Original Ctn | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The `products` table contains the following columns: `ID`, `NAME`, `SUB_CATEGORY`.

The `stockckdiary` table contains the following columns:  `PRODUCT`, `DATENEW`, `UNITS`.

Comment: Please  go to dbfiddle.uk and construct your table, input your data and please provide your desired result.

Comment: Read about pivoting.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT name,
       ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN datenew BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
                                 AND CURRENT_DATE 
                    THEN units
                    ELSE 0
                    END)) AS wk1,
       ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN datenew BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 14 DAY 
                                 AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 8 DAY
                    THEN units
                    ELSE 0
                    END)) AS wk2,
       ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN datenew BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 21 DAY 
                                 AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 15 DAY
                    THEN units
                    ELSE 0
                    END)) AS wk3
FROM products 
INNER JOIN stockdiary ON stockdiary.product = products.id  
WHERE sub_category='LB40' 
  AND datenew BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 21 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE
  AND reason = -1
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY category;
```

Comment: @Raf - See [what to do when someone answers my question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).